# Submit multiple Inputs in React to Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to fetch my lat lng coords in reactJs but it does not seem to work
can anyone give me an answer what I'm doing wrong?

```
componentDidMount (){
  fetch("https://ipinfo.io/loc")
  .then(d => d.json())
  .then(d => {
    this.setState({
      data: d
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What part doesn't work for you? Can you elaborate more?